# Reverse tomography to create 3D scalpel

Tags: radiation, medicine

Isn't it possible to reverse tomography methods to create means to deliver heat or radiation precisely in 3D? This would be "3D scalpel" i.e. device which would be able to eradicate tumor cells precisely in otherwise unreachable areas?

Comment: This is the idea behind http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiosurgery (a.k.a., "Gamma knife")

Comment: Some people are also studying that kind of things with ultrasounds using [time reversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_reversal_signal_processing). For example against [kidney stones](http://ohm.bu.edu/~pbohn/TIME_MIRROR/Research/getPDF.pdf). But ultrasounds have problems (mainly because of their wavelength) and are not that easy to use against tumours in unreachable areas. I think there are also studies about time reversal for electromagnetic waves, but that also yields some problems.

Answer (score 1):

The principle of targeting cancers with high intensity radiation is already in use. For example:

http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/gamma-knife-radiosurgery/basics/definition/prc-20014760